# How do I have a page depth > 1 on a single page website?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

One of my sites is a single page that focuses on getting the user to call a phone number.

In GA, I've set up a Goal for when visitors spend more than 1 minute on the site. I realized much later that GA doesn't trap exit events, so visitors who arrive at the site and click back won't be counted. I'd like to modify that; but that's for another question.

I've got a number of users with an Average Time on Site >0 ; and a page depth > 1. I can't figure out how --- My site contains a single page.

The number of users with Page Depth 2+ doesn't equal the number of returning visitors - otherwise I'd assume these are people who left and then typed in the url manually.

I'm at a loss. Did they just hit refresh? Did they bookmark the site and return to it? (That shouldn't count as 'time on site' though'...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Page depth does not take into account unique pageviews, just total pageviews. So, yes, if your end user refreshes the page in any way, it'll count as a two-page visit.

If they bookmark the page and return to it a few hours later, its a new visit, and doesn't alter the previous visit's page depth.